# How to create a search language?

Tags: javascript, parsing, search, string-parsing

I would like to create a simple filtering language in Javascript.

I want to search inside a collection of products, say:

```
product=[
   {price:10,name:"T-Shirt",category:"Clothing",published_at:"07-08-2014",size:"10x30",color:"#0000FF"},
   {price:20,name:"Chair",category:"Furniture",published_at:"09-03-2013",size:"30x30",color:"#00FF00"},
   {price:30,name:"iPhone",category:"Phones",published_at:"17-03-2014",size:"40x30",color:"#FF00FF"},
   {price:40,name:"Samsung Galaxy",category:"Phones",published_at:"12-01-2012",size:"10x60",color:"#00BBBB"},
];
```

With only one input of text, I would like to be able to query inside this array, for example:

- `cat:Clothing` =>  gives back the tshirt
- `price:>15` => gives back Chair, iPhone, and Samsung Galaxy
- `name:iP` => Filters trough the names and gives back iPhone
- `price:>15&&size:>35x25` => Filters trough the names and gives back iPhone

I know they are some language parsers like

- https://github.com/tolmasky/language
- https://github.com/zaach/jison (used by coffeescript)

but I don't know which one to choose (and why) and if it is a good idea to use one ? Any ideas ?

Comment: wouldn't it be more useful to have a DB on server and ask it via ajax?

Comment: Have a look at AngularJS filters. Might be an overkill, but still, nice to look at

Comment: The question is more about how to create your language, it can be translated into a DB language at the end, or in native Javascript. Angular JS filters won't parse a language I invented (it's not magic) @NikhilBaliga

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452584/building-a-parser-part-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to test with JISON (Similar to BISON)

```
/* description: Parses end executes mathematical expressions. */

/* lexical grammar */
%lex
%%

\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?\b  return 'NUMBER'
">"                     return '>'
"price:"              return 'PRICE'
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF'
"name:"               return 'NAME'
[a-z]+                return 'STRING'
","                   return 'COMMA'


/lex

/* operator associations and precedence */

%left 'COMMA'
%left 'PRICE' 'NAME'


%start expressions

%% /* language grammar */

expressions
    : e EOF
        { typeof console !== 'undefined' ? console.log($1) : print($1);
          return $1; }
    ;

e
    : 'PRICE' '>' e
        {$$ = {price:{gt:$3}};}
    | 'NAME' e
        {$$ = {name:{contains:$2}};}
    | NUMBER
        {$$ = Number(yytext);}
    | STRING
        {$$ = String(yytext);}
    | e 'COMMA' e
        { for (var attrname in $1) { $3[attrname]=$1[attrname]; $$ = $3; }}
    ;
```

The result of the parser is the following:

`price:>30` **=>** `{ price: { gt: 30 } }`

`name:blabla,price:>10` **=>** `{ price: { gt: 10 }, name: { contains: 'blabla' } }`

`name:test` **=>** `{ name: { contains: 'test' } }`

This solution seems a bit more portable to me, because it doesn't directly deal with the parsing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is simple enough to do yourself without a library.

Here's my crack at it:

**http://jsfiddle.net/qrz48/2/**

```
// polyfill Array.prototype.forEach if you need to support older browsers...
// there's one at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

var product = [
    {price:10,name:"T-Shirt",category:"Clothing",published_at:"07-08-2014",size:"10x30",color:"#0000FF"},
    {price:20,name:"Chair",category:"Furniture",published_at:"09-03-2013",size:"30x30",color:"#00FF00"},
    {price:30,name:"iPhone",category:"Phones",published_at:"17-03-2014",size:"40x30",color:"#FF00FF"},
    {price:40,name:"Samsung Galaxy",category:"Phones",published_at:"12-01-2012",size:"10x60",color:"#00BBBB"}
];

// extend this as you require new search operators.
var operators = {
    "==": function(a, b) {return a == b;},
    "===": function(a, b) {return a === b;},
    ">": function(a, b) {return a > b;},
    ">=": function(a, b) {return a >= b;},
    "<": function(a, b) {return a < b;},
    "<=": function(a, b) {return a <= b;},
    "*": function(a, b) {return a.indexOf(b) > -1;}
};

// usage: find("category", "===", "Clothing")
function find(key, operator, condition, searchIn) {
    if( ! searchIn) {
        searchIn = product;
    }
    var result = [];
    searchIn.forEach(function(item) {
        if(operators[operator](item[key], condition)) {
            result.push(item);
        }
    });
    return result;
}

// usage: query("category:===:Clothing");
function query(str) {
    var conditions = str.split("&&");
    var result = [];
    conditions.forEach(function(condition, index) {
        var parts = condition.split(":");
        var key = parts[0];
        var operator = parts[1];
        var condition = parts[2];
        var searchIn = (conditions.length > 1 && index > 0) ? result : null;
        result = find(key, operator, condition, searchIn);
    });
    return result;
}


// usage
console.log(query("category:===:Clothing"));
console.log(query("price:>:20"));
console.log(query("name:*:iP"));
console.log(query("price:>:20&&name:*:Galaxy"));
```

You can pass a search string to the `query` function above, as requested, with the exception that a colon is required both before and after the condition operator. For example, to find all products where the price is greater than 20, run:

```
query("price:>:20");
```

You can also combine search conditions using the format in your question:

```
query("price:>:20&&category:===:Clothing");
```

I couldn't think how to do your `size` comparison without splitting the size data out into separate values, e.g. `sizeX` and `sizeY`, which would be easier to compare using something like

```
query("sizeX:>:30&&sizeY:>:20");
```

If anything this was just quite fun to write. What do you think?

Comment: It's great, I would not think it to be that easy to write such a language. I wrote a language parser in JISON during the meantime. Still need to think which solution I will use

Comment: I'd stick with whichever seems easier to maintain for you, would be easiest to understand by any future developers working on the project, and has the least dependencies on other libraries.