# How to use Parse in java project Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parse-platform, server

I want to let user able to sign in and sign up in my java application and play the game and the program will send important information on that user such as username and score to the parse server and receive it with android application using parse

But since parse.com doesn't support on pc, how do I do it?
 I've been familiar with parse on android but not on pc and i don't know any other database. Is there any other solution for this? like another online database that can connect on both pc and android.

Thank you

Comment: why you're stuck with parse.com ? you can build your own parser..

Comment: I don't know anything about it. Do you have an example? Thank you

Comment: I see Java as being listed... https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries

Comment: see this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220042/Easily-Create-Your-Own-Parser and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452584/building-a-parser-part-i