# Creating grammar for basic parser in scala

Tags: scala, parsing

I wish to write a basic parser in **Scala**. Few years back I had worked on a java project in which we had created a financial parser for tax calculation.

Here is what the text that I wish to parse will contain:

1) Basic expression using equality, logical operators.
2) Conditions limited to IF, AND, OR.
3) Result of string type printed on console.

Eg "IF X =='text' and Y==2 Result SUCCESS"

I have read the Scala Combinator parser from "Programming in Scala", got some idea. Want to understand the process of creating grammar based on my requirement.

From what I have read, I think I need few abstracts to make a language.
1) Expression syntax
2) Operator syntax
3) Literals / Tokens syntax

Adding an initial code from what I think it should have:

```
class BasicParser extends JavaTokenParsers{

def literals : Parser[Any] = stringLiteral| floatingPointNumber | "null" |   decimalNumber

def conditions: Parser[Any] = "["~repsep(literals, "AND") | repsep(literals, "OR")~"]"

//added later
def expression: Parser[Any] = "["~repsep(literals, conditions) ~"]"

}
```

Is there anything else that I should have to create grammar for this parser?

Update: Ok, I went back to drawing board and thought about proper approach to this problem.

For any parser to be defined, we would need to define what tokens it would have.
Then we should define what operators if would have, if any.
Then we should define the expression to represent in what form the tokens and operators will exist.

Here is my code updated based on these points, I still think there are a few gaps here.

```
class BasicParser extends JavaTokenParsers{

def literals : Parser[Any] = stringLiteral | floatingPointNumber | decimalNumber

def conditions: Parser[(String, String)=> Boolean]  = ("AND" | "OR" | "IF") ^^ {
case "AND" => AND

case "OR" => OR

case "IF" => IFExpr

}

 def AND(s1: String, s2:String): Boolean = {
// convert text and use AND ( && )

false
}

def OR(s1: String, s2:String):Boolean= {
// convert text and use OR( || )
false
}

def IFExpr(s: String, x: String): Boolean={
// convert s into condition
if(s)
  true
else
  false
}

def expression: Parser[Any] = literals | conditions

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a parser (Part I)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452584/building-a-parser-part-i)

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I wish to implement it using Scala. Without using a chain of if-else statements.

Comment: I am trying to parse just the string literals for start. My definitions are following:    def literals : Parser[Any] = stringLiteral; def expression: Parser[Any] = repsep(expression, " ");  def evaluate(input: String) = parseAll(expression, input);  This is not working for input "ONE TWO THREE".   It only parses ONE. What am I missing here?